# Stream linux cut line by line

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, cut, gnu-coreutils

I'd like to pass lines through cut line-by-line (much like `egrep --line-buffered`). How can I do this? [`awk`, `sed`, `perl` solutions welcome, just please keep them short. :)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to emulate the function of cut in a loop in UNIX (which can be quite slow), you can use awk's *substr* function.

e.g., say you have a text file (lines.txt) that's arranged like this:

```
line1: the first line
line2: the second line
line3: the third line
line4: the fourth line
line5: the fifth line
```

With this one-liner, where **8** is the index of the character you want to start printing each the line from:

```
awk '{ print substr($0,8) }' lines.txt
```

This is the result:

```
the first line
the second line
the third line
the fourth line
the fifth line
```

If you have a specific word or regexp to remove, you can feed it into awk as a field separator and then print the portion of the line that comes after the portion you would like removed:

For example, this one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=": " } { print $2 }' lines.txt
```

Would also print out:

```
the first line
the second line
the third line
the fourth line
the fifth line
```

Because you can exploit the fact that each line contains a semicolon followed by a space **(": ")** to divide the line into two parts. Then you simply tell awk to print the second part (i.e. field) of each line **(print $2)**.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I had no idea awk was line buffered. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) awk's *default* behavior is to assume each line is a separate unit of input, or "record". If you want to change this behavior, you can set the "record separator" or "RS" in the "BEGIN" block, i.e., 'BEGIN { RS="x" }'; in this case, it would work as though the letter "x" indicates the start of each record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stdbuf` utility to control the stdio buffering of any command that uses stdio

```
... | stdbuf -oL cut ... | ...
```

Comment: This works, but appears to make the stream lag by one line.